# Flutter: How to output json data as a marker on Google Maps

Tags: json, flutter, google-maps-markers

I am implementing an app that tries to print shop json data as a marker on Google Maps through http request.
I use a future and package:http/http.dart to get a json array

```
`Future<List<Shop>> fetchJson() async {
  late List<Shop> shopList;
    String url = "https://openapi.gg.go.kr/GGGOODINFLSTOREST?KEY=myapikey&Type=json&pIndex=1&pSize=20";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final responseBody = response.body;

  final jsonMap = json.decode(responseBody);

  shopList = jsonMap.containsKey("GGGOODINFLSTOREST")
      ? (jsonMap['GGGOODINFLSTOREST'][1]['row'] as List)
      .map((e) => Shop.fromJson(e))
      .toList()
      : List.empty();
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    return shopList;
  }else{
    throw Exception('Failed to load shop info');
  }
}`
```

It was successful to print json data as a list through the code above, but it is difficult to print it as a marker on Google Maps.
I want to print out the store information, latitude, and longitude to be used in the list as a marker.
The list part is as follows.

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> places = [  {    'name': 'shop1',    'refineWgs84Lat':  ,    'refineWgs84Logt': ,  },];
```

The following is the code that prints google map

```
 GoogleMap(
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                          target: LatLng(37.532600, 127.024612), 
                          zoom: 18,
                        ),
                        markers: Set<Marker>.of(shops.map((shop) {
                          return Marker(
                            markerId: MarkerId(shop['cmpnmNm']),
                            position: LatLng(shop['refineWgs84Lat'],
                                shop['refineWgs84Logt']),
                            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: shop['cmpnmNm']),
                          );
                        }
                        ))),
```

`
The json file is as follows.

```
`class Shop {
  final String cmpnmNm;          // shopname
  final String indutypeNm;
  final String sigunNm;
  final String bsnTmNm;
  final String provsnProdlstNm;
  final String bizregno;
  final String provsnTrgtNm2;
  final String refineLotnoAddr;
  final String refineZipno;
  final String refineWgs84Lat;          // shop latitude
  final String refineWgs84Logt;         // shop longitude
  final String detailAddr;
  final String provsnTrgtNm1;
  final String refineRoadnmAddr;

  Shop({
    required this.cmpnmNm,
    required this.indutypeNm,
    required this.sigunNm,
    required this.bsnTmNm,
    required this.provsnProdlstNm,
    required this.bizregno,
    required this.provsnTrgtNm2,
    required this.refineLotnoAddr,
    required this.refineZipno,
    required this.refineWgs84Lat,
    required this.refineWgs84Logt,
    required this.detailAddr,
    required this.provsnTrgtNm1,
    required this.refineRoadnmAddr,
  });

  Shop.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : cmpnmNm=json["CMPNM_NM"] as String,
        indutypeNm= json["INDUTYPE_NM"] as String,
        sigunNm= json["SIGUN_NM"] as String,
        bsnTmNm= json["BSN_TM_NM"] as String,
        provsnProdlstNm= json["PROVSN_PRODLST_NM"] as String,
        bizregno= json["BIZREGNO"] as String,
        provsnTrgtNm2= json["PROVSN_TRGT_NM2"] as String,
        refineLotnoAddr= json["REFINE_LOTNO_ADDR"] as String,
        refineZipno= json["REFINE_ZIPNO"] as String,
        refineWgs84Lat= json["REFINE_WGS84_LAT"] as String,
        refineWgs84Logt= json["REFINE_WGS84_LOGT"] as String,
        detailAddr= json["DETAIL_ADDR"] as String,
        provsnTrgtNm1= json["PROVSN_TRGT_NM1"] as String,
        refineRoadnmAddr= json["REFINE_ROADNM_ADDR"] as String;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "CMPNM_NM": cmpnmNm,
    "INDUTYPE_NM": indutypeNm,
    "SIGUN_NM": sigunNm,
    "BSN_TM_NM": bsnTmNm,
    "PROVSN_PRODLST_NM": provsnProdlstNm,
    "BIZREGNO": bizregno,
    "PROVSN_TRGT_NM2": provsnTrgtNm2,
    "REFINE_LOTNO_ADDR": refineLotnoAddr,
    "REFINE_ZIPNO": refineZipno,
    "REFINE_WGS84_LAT": refineWgs84Lat,
    "REFINE_WGS84_LOGT": refineWgs84Logt,
    "DETAIL_ADDR": detailAddr,
    "PROVSN_TRGT_NM1": provsnTrgtNm1,
    "REFINE_ROADNM_ADDR": refineRoadnmAddr
  };
}
```

`
Tried as above but no marker seen on the map. I've been doing it for three weeks, so I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you get any error messages in your console? Also at the top your mentioned a variable named shopList but on the GoogleMap there is a variable named shops, can you explain it?

Comment: It was printed as a list to see if json data is output for testing before loading into the map.